# Redirect root of website only with apache and .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to redirect only the root of my domain to another domain with apache + .htaccess - However I would like to maintain current directories.

Example:

http://www.domain-one.com/ would redirect to http://www.domain-two.com/

However anything after the / would be ignored, examples:

http://www.domain-one.com/contact

http://www.domain-one.com/?param=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in the site root `.htaccess` of `domain-one`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain-one\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain-two.com/ [L,R=301]
```